# Convert two lists to dictionary with values as list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

I can convert two lists to dictionary

```
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> print dictionary
```

How to convert it to dictionary with keys but values as list.

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'a']
values=[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1,4], 'c': [3], 'b': [2]}
```

I am using this in dependency parser to get corresponding adjectives for nouns in text.
Note I have to do this for huge text so efficency matters.

Please state the computational time of approach as well.

Comment: You can't use `zip` here as you have multiple instances of the same key

Comment: @EdChum Yeah I know zip doesn't work.

Comment: can you have more keys than values?

Comment: No keys and values are the same length.  Until something weird happens will check once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141383/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-duplicate-keys-in-python-dictionary

Comment: So don't do this:
`dict(zip(set(keys), [[values[i] for i, x in enumerate(keys) if x == s] for s in set(keys)]))` I mean do that, because it's hilarious and it works, but definitely don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd simply loop over the key/value pairs and use `setdefault` to add them to the dictionary:

```
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'a']
>>> values=[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d = {}
>>> for k,v in zip(keys, values):
...     d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
...     
>>> d
{'c': [3], 'b': [2], 'a': [1, 4]}
```

Comment: I might add a link to the function https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault - so that future browsers can have a look what it does...

Answer (score 2):

Presuming both lists have the same length:

```
>>> import collections
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'a']
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> r = collections.defaultdict(list)

>>> for i, key in enumerate(keys):
...     r[key].append(values[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) takes a list and groups neighboring same elements together. We need to sort the zipped list to ensure that equal keys end up next to each other.

```
import itertools
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
data = sorted(zip(keys, values))
dictionary = {}
for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    dictionary[k] = [x[1] for x in g]
print(dictionary)
# {'c': [3], 'b': [2], 'a': [1, 4]}
```

Comment: why is `sorted` needed?

Comment: because that's the contract of groupby, it groups contiguous items with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this. But here's one solution:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'a']
values=[1, 2, 3, 4]

combined = {}

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    l = combined.get(k, [])
    l.append(v)
    combined[k] = l
```