# printing unique key-value and skipping the same value-key in dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I have this dictionary and I don’t want to print (the key and the value) if they already exist (as value and key) or vice versa.

I want to print (orange and apple) and (Strawberry and Grapes) for once.

```
{
'Orange'    : ‘Apple’,
‘Orange'    : ‘Banana’, 
’Strawberry': ‘Grapes’, 
‘Apple'     : ‘Orange’,
‘Blackberry': ‘Banana’, 
’Cherry'    : ‘Fig’, 
’Grapes'    : ‘Strawberry’ 
 }
```

Expexted output:

```
Orange Apple
Orange Banana
Strawberry Grapes
BlackBerry Banana
Cherry Fig
```

Comment: You can't have a dictionary with duplicate keys. If "Orange" is the key for "apple", it can't be the key for "banana". Please provide an actual legal dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Having duplicate keys sort of violates the purpose of a dictionary in python. There are ways around it [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141570/5415084) but I wouldn't suggest it.