# Error message "TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'dict'"

Tags: python

In the *for* loop I have a dictionary object like this:

```
mob1 = {
    "Item": item1,
    'Price': price1,
    'Desc': desc1
}
```

And I tried to append it like:

```
list.append(mob1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/turbolab/Documents/python_test/Sep 23 data_to_json test.json", line 32, in <module>
    list.append(mob1)
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'dict'
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? What elements of the dictionary to you want appended in the list? Without sufficiently describing your issue you make it difficult for others to help you out.

Comment: as i am trying to get the name, its price and the description of an item from a webpage, when i loaded it to the json file, iam getting only the name, price and description of the last item only, its getting overwritten so i used list.append() in the for loop after dictionary

Comment: Why do you have a python file named `test.json` ? Also list.append expects a list object not a dict and even if it did work it would not do anything useful

Comment: This is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141383/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-duplicate-keys-in-python-dictionary

Comment: am trying to get the data in json format. Here mob1 is a my data variable. when i print mob1 inside the loop before loading it to json, it was working with zero errors. after loading the data to json im getting only the last item

Comment: It was probably parens. The OP does not show the list variable being initialized. This error message can result from initializing the list variable incorrectly by leaving out the parens. Initializing as `mylist = list` will produce the error in question when `mylist.append("something")` is called, whereas with the following initialization it will work fine (note the parens): `mylist = list()`.

Comment: @codingoutloud answer is correct. For better clarification of error see this page https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0580/#id12.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`list` is a class. `append` is a method of that class which has to be called on instances of `list`.

```
list.append(7)  # error

mylist = list()
mylist.append(7)  # ok
```

Comment: i am a beginner please make it clear, what is 7?? an object?? mob1 is my object where i stored my data and i need to replace mob1 with 7 right?

Comment: @arjun Everything is an object, but that is not relevant here. If you want to create many dict objects (like your `mob1`), first create an empty list `many_mobs = []` and then put mobs into it `may_mobs.append(mob1)` as many times as you want.

Comment: i have edited it like this;          mob1 = {
    "Item": item1,
    'Price': price1,
    'Desc': desc1
    }

 mylist = []
 mylist.append(mob1)
 print mob1                  //still am getting the complete list of data in cmd prompt but when it is loaded to a json file the problem remains same (i,e) getting only the details of last item only. there are 10 items and am getting only the details of 10th item only like it is overwritten

Comment: @arjun I'd have to see the rest of the code to understand what is wrong.

Comment: i got the output...  just inserted mylist = [ ] inside the loop. when it is written oustide the for loop the problem is solved... thank you :)

Answer (score -3):

Try:

`list.append([mob1['Item'],mob1['Price'],mob1['Desc']])`

Comment: yes i have tried this but does not work unfortunatley