# Python duplicate keys in a dictionary.(one - many relation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I wrote a below python script to print all the values associated with keys in a python dictionary. I created python dictionary using values from rest api calls I made. The dictionary has duplicate keys.

```
dict = {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'}.
```

I have been through post [Is there a way to preserve duplicate keys in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141383/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-duplicate-keys-in-python-dictionary).

I am able to get the desired output using below script

```
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)

val=input("Enter a vlaue:")

for k, v in (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')):

     data[k].append(v)

#print(list(data.keys()))

if str(val) in list(data.keys()):

    for i in data[val]:

        print(i)
```

I am struck at converting dictionary to tuple of tuples.
eg:
`{'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'}` to `(('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'))`. Is there is a way to do this without changing the duplication value (I need duplicate keys)?

Answer (score 0):

your dict does not have duplicate keys, that is not possible in python without monkey patching

what you have created is a dictionary of lists that contain the values
`{a:[b,c],b:[d]}`

to convert such a dict into tuples, simply iterate over the lists

```
data = {"a":["b","c"], "b":["d"]}

def to_tuples(data_dictionary):
    for key, values in data_dictionary.items():
        for value in values:
            yield key, value

print(list(to_tuples(data)))
>>>[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'g')]
```

Comment: My ask is to convert dictionary {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} to (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')). or please let me know how to convert  {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} to {"a":["b","c"], "b":["d"]}.

Comment: when you write {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} in python, it discards the 'a':'b' part, duplicate keys do not exist in python, the code you have written in your question creates {"a":["b","c"], "b":["d"]} and you asked to convert it to tuples...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this what you want:

```
>>> import collections
>>> 
>>> data = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for k, v in (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')):
...     data[k].append(v)
... 
>>> print(dict(data))
{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['c']}
>>> 
>>> l = []
>>> for k, v in data.items():
...     l.extend((k, v2) for v2 in v)
... 
>>> print(tuple(l))
(('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'))
```

Hope it helps. =)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't help. My ask is to convert dictionary {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} to (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'))

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to proceed. How would you relate `b` and `c`? In your sample code you provide a dict in the form of `{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['c']}` which clearly makes `b` related to `c` but the one you provide in the question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have unique keys. This does what I think you want:

```
data = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['c']}

data_tuples = tuple((k, i) for k, v in data.items() for i in v)

# output: (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'))
```

Comment: My ask is to convert dictionary {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} to (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')). or please let me know how to convert {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} to {"a":["b","c"], "b":["d"]}

Comment: My answer is {'a':'b', 'a':'c', 'b':'d'} is not a dictionary. A dictionary may not have duplicate keys.