# Why are there missing records when I convert from pandas df to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, arcpy

I am trying to convert a DBF of about 3233 records created from a shapefile of US counties to a dataframe; then I want to take two of the columns from that dataframe and **convert to a dictionary where `column1` is the key and `column2` is the value**. However, the resulting dictionary doesn't have the same number of records as my dataframe.

- I use arcpy to call in the shapefile for all US Counties. When I use arcpy.GetCount_management(county_shapefile), this returns a feature count of 3233 records.
- In order to convert to a dataframe, I converted to a dbf first with arcpy.TableToTableconversion(), this returns a dbf with 3233 records.
- After converting to a df using Dbf5 from simpledbf, I get a df with 3233 records.
- **I then convert the first two columns to a dictionary which returns 56 records**. Can anyone tell me what's going on here? (I recently switched to Python 3 from Python 2, could that be part of the issue?)

Code:

```
county_shapefile = "U:/Shapefiles/tl_2018_us_county/tl_2018_us_county.shp"
dbf = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(county_shapefile,"U:/","county_data.dbf")

from simpledbf import Dbf5
dbfile = Dbf5(str(dbf))
df = dbfile.to_dataframe()

df_dict = {row[0]:row[1] for row in df.values}
```

I have also tried doing this with the `.to_dict()` function, but I'm not getting the desired dictionary structure {column1:column2,column1:column2...}

```
from simpledbf import Dbf5
dbfile=Dbf5(str(dbf))
df=dbfile.to_dataframe()
subset=df[["STATEFP","COUNTYFP"]]
subset=subset.set_index("COUNTYFP")
dict=subset.to_dict()
```

In the end, I'm hoping to create a dictionary where the key is the County FIPS code (COUNTYFP) and the value is the State FIPS code (STATEFP). I do not want to have any nested dictionaries, just a simple dictionary with the format...

```
dict={
   COUNTYFP1:STATEFP1,
   COUNTYFP2:STATEFP2,
   COUNTYFP3:STATEFP3,
   ....
}
```

Comment: Have you played with the `orient=` keyword in `df.to_dict()` (`‘dict’, ‘list’, ‘series’, ‘split’, ‘records’, ‘index’`) to see if one of the available options gets you to the correct format?

Comment: There aren't missing records; just multiple records for the same key. **56 keys is suspiciously close to the ~56 FIPS State(/District/Territory) codes for 50 states+DC+ AS, FM, GU, PR, VI**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the `column1` has no duplicates? Because dictionaries in python do not support duplicate keys! If you want to preserve all the values in the `column1` as keys you'll have to find a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python) for the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141383/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-duplicate-keys-in-python-dictionary).

Comment: I was able to concatenate two of the identifying columns to create a unique key. Thank you