# missing args when convering list to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

random list args just not includes in mydict and disappear and i dont know what to do.
my code -

```
def openOrSenior(data):
    data = dict(data)
    print(data)
    output = []
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k >= 55 and v > 7:
            output += ['Senior']
        else:
            output += ['Open']
    return output
print(openOrSenior( [[17, 18], [57, 25], [56, 24], [41, 2], [22, 27], [48, 15], [39, 21], [41, 2]] ))
```

output-

```
{17: 18, 57: 25, 56: 24, 41: 2, 22: 27, 48: 15, 39: 21}
['Open', 'Senior', 'Senior', 'Open', 'Open', 'Open', 'Open']
```

where is [41, 2]?
it happens sometimes with diferent numbers and places in list, so i can't understand where is the problem.
I need it for this kata in codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/5502c9e7b3216ec63c0001aa/train/python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to preserve duplicate keys in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141383/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-duplicate-keys-in-python-dictionary) ... there are others searching with variations of `python dict duplicate key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k = 41 (4th item) was already in this list... Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys and it considers the last occurrence of k = 41 which is [41, 2].

Answer (score 1):

keys in a dict are unique, so you are overwriting the key `41` shrinking the expected output, to fix you can use:

```
def openOrSenior(data):
    output = []
    for k, v in data:
        if k >= 55 and v > 7:
            output += ['Senior']
        else:
            output += ['Open']
    return output
print(openOrSenior( [[17, 18], [57, 25], [56, 24], [41, 2], [22, 27], [48, 15], [39, 21], [41, 2]] ))
```

output:

```
['Open', 'Senior', 'Senior', 'Open', 'Open', 'Open', 'Open', 'Open']
```

as you can see  the inner lists are unpacked in 2 variables, `k` and `v`

---

or you can use a list comprehension:

```
def openOrSenior(data):
    return ['Senior' if k>=55 and v>=6 else 'Open' for k, v in data]
```